# How to get HTML text in unicode?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Can not get proper string of HTML.

Hello, I am trying to get HTML from webView in android but it returns me not usable string with backslashes and decoded characters. I want to know ho to fix this. Here is my code:

```
    webViewOne.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.evaluateJavascript("(function() {var allHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML; return allHtml; })();",
                    new ValueCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceiveValue(String s) {

                            Log.d("sss", s);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
```

Here I am using javascript to get body of HTML document:

`var allHtml = document.documentElement.innerHTML; return allHtml;`

But it returns me: `"\u003Chead>\n\n\u003Ctitle...` .

Is it possible to get proper string in unicode manipulating only javascript?